# how to upload selected contacts into a webserver

Tags: android

I want to upload the selected contacts (phonebook-android)into webserver....can any one help me...please show me the code..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is really based on what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to stream them as an XML file? Is this being uploaded to a database? Or is this just a simple text file that is going to an ftp server?  These things matter a lot in the answer. Maybe make your post a little bit more clear.  If you wanted to put them in a MySql database for example.  You could use the java.sql library, which you can learn more about here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Now as for getting a list that you can select from and put into a data structure, I would use something like this from a previous post:

```
   Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
List contactlist = new ArrayList();
while(people.moveToNext()) {
   contactList.Add(people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
   contactList.Add(people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
   contactList.Add(people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
   contactList.Add(people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
}

people.close();
```

Credit: Javier Figueroa

Pretty much use a content resolver to grab the name and number put into an array list then put them into a ListView, have the person select them and then from there use the transfer method of your choice.